# Error : Invalid number of channels in input image: 'VScn::contains(scn)' using opencv?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to unshear the image , just like cam scanner does, It is working for some images , IfI give any random image it is not working , The image named as new_image.jpeg is not working and image named as 1111.jpeg is working . Although the picture is totally same .

**Code:**

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import re
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')


# ## **Use Gaussian Blurring combined with Adaptive Threshold** 

def blur_and_threshold(gray):
    gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(3,3),2)
    threshold = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)
    threshold = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoising(threshold, 11, 31, 9)
    return threshold


# ## **Find the Biggest Contour** 

# **Note: We made sure the minimum contour is bigger than 1/10 size of the whole picture. This helps in removing very small contours (noise) from our dataset**


def biggest_contour(contours,min_area):
    biggest = None
    max_area = 0
    biggest_n=0
    approx_contour=None
    for n,i in enumerate(contours):
            area = cv2.contourArea(i)
            if area > min_area/10:
                    peri = cv2.arcLength(i,True)
                    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(i,0.02*peri,True)
                    if area > max_area and len(approx)==4:
                            biggest = approx
                            max_area = area
                            biggest_n=n
                            approx_contour=approx                                                                         
    return biggest_n,approx_contour


def order_points(pts):
    # initialzie a list of coordinates that will be ordered
    # such that the first entry in the list is the top-left,
    # the second entry is the top-right, the third is the
    # bottom-right, and the fourth is the bottom-left
    pts=pts.reshape(4,2)
    rect = np.zeros((4, 2), dtype = "float32")

    # the top-left point will have the smallest sum, whereas
    # the bottom-right point will have the largest sum
    s = pts.sum(axis = 1)
    rect[0] = pts[np.argmin(s)]
    rect[2] = pts[np.argmax(s)]

    # now, compute the difference between the points, the
    # top-right point will have the smallest difference,
    # whereas the bottom-left will have the largest difference
    diff = np.diff(pts, axis = 1)
    rect[1] = pts[np.argmin(diff)]
    rect[3] = pts[np.argmax(diff)]

    # return the ordered coordinates
    return rect


### Find the exact (x,y) coordinates of the biggest contour and crop it out
def four_point_transform(image, pts):
    # obtain a consistent order of the points and unpack them
    # individually
    rect = order_points(pts)
    (tl, tr, br, bl) = rect

    # compute the width of the new image, which will be the
    # maximum distance between bottom-right and bottom-left
    # x-coordiates or the top-right and top-left x-coordinates
    widthA = np.sqrt(((br[0] - bl[0]) ** 2) + ((br[1] - bl[1]) ** 2))
    widthB = np.sqrt(((tr[0] - tl[0]) ** 2) + ((tr[1] - tl[1]) ** 2))
    maxWidth = max(int(widthA), int(widthB))
   

    # compute the height of the new image, which will be the
    # maximum distance between the top-right and bottom-right
    # y-coordinates or the top-left and bottom-left y-coordinates
    heightA = np.sqrt(((tr[0] - br[0]) ** 2) + ((tr[1] - br[1]) ** 2))
    heightB = np.sqrt(((tl[0] - bl[0]) ** 2) + ((tl[1] - bl[1]) ** 2))
    maxHeight = max(int(heightA), int(heightB))

    # now that we have the dimensions of the new image, construct
    # the set of destination points to obtain a "birds eye view",
    # (i.e. top-down view) of the image, again specifying points
    # in the top-left, top-right, bottom-right, and bottom-left
    # order
    dst = np.array([
        [0, 0],
        [maxWidth - 1, 0],
        [maxWidth - 1, maxHeight - 1],
        [0, maxHeight - 1]], dtype = "float32")

    # compute the perspective transform matrix and then apply it
    M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(rect, dst)
    warped = cv2.warpPerspective(image, M, (maxWidth, maxHeight))

    # return the warped image
    return warped


# # Transformation the image

# **1. Convert the image to grayscale**

# **2. Remove noise and smoothen out the image by applying blurring and thresholding techniques**

# **3. Use Canny Edge Detection to find the edges**

# **4. Find the biggest contour and crop it out**


def transformation(image):
    image=image.copy()  
    height, width, channels = image.shape
    gray=cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    image_size=gray.size
  
    threshold=blur_and_threshold(gray)
    # We need two threshold values, minVal and maxVal. Any edges with intensity gradient more than maxVal 
    # are sure to be edges and those below minVal are sure to be non-edges, so discarded. 
    #  Those who lie between these two thresholds are classified edges or non-edges based on their connectivity.
    # If they are connected to "sure-edge" pixels, they are considered to be part of edges. 
    #  Otherwise, they are also discarded
    edges = cv2.Canny(threshold,50,150,apertureSize = 7)
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edges, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    simplified_contours = []


    for cnt in contours:
        hull = cv2.convexHull(cnt)
        simplified_contours.append(cv2.approxPolyDP(hull,
                                0.001*cv2.arcLength(hull,True),True))
    simplified_contours = np.array(simplified_contours)
    biggest_n,approx_contour = biggest_contour(simplified_contours,image_size)

    threshold = cv2.drawContours(image, simplified_contours ,biggest_n, (0,255,0), 1)

    dst = 0
    if approx_contour is not None and len(approx_contour)==4:
        approx_contour=np.float32(approx_contour)
        dst=four_point_transform(threshold,approx_contour)
    croppedImage = dst
    return croppedImage


# **Increase the brightness of the image by playing with the "V" value (from HSV)**

def increase_brightness(img, value=30):
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    h, s, v = cv2.split(hsv)
    lim = 255 - value
    v[v > lim] = 255
    v[v <= lim] += value
    final_hsv = cv2.merge((h, s, v))
    img = cv2.cvtColor(final_hsv, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
    return img  


# **Sharpen the image using Kernel Sharpening Technique**


def final_image(rotated):
    # Create our shapening kernel, it must equal to one eventually
    kernel_sharpening = np.array([[0,-1,0], 
                                [-1, 5,-1],
                                [0,-1,0]])
    # applying the sharpening kernel to the input image & displaying it.
    sharpened = cv2.filter2D(rotated, -1, kernel_sharpening)
    sharpened=increase_brightness(sharpened,30)  
    return sharpened


# ## 1. Pass the image through the transformation function to crop out the biggest contour

# ## 2. Brighten & Sharpen the image to get a final cleaned image

path = "/home/hamza/Desktop/"
image = cv2.imread("path of image")    

blurred_threshold = transformation(image)
cleaned_image = final_image(blurred_threshold)
cv2.imwrite(path + "Final_Image4.jpg", cleaned_image)
```

**Pictures**

1. [first pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFuiw.jpg)
2. [second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohovh.jpg)

**Edit 1:**

Picture 1  [test image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrMeQ.jpg)

Picture 2  [test image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYEvB.jpg)

Picture 3  [test image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZfIl.jpg)

Picture 4  [test image 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEv6u.jpg)

**Edit 2:**
If I just pass only black and white image can it remove shearness , you may try it if it works please share with me .

**Pic:**

[black and white image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OsyVM.jpg)

**Note:** If image comes unsheared , then that particular image should displayed exactly same means code should not touched it . Hope so you got the point.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is wrong with your images, I tested your code and indeed the first image works with the code as you wrote it, for the second image, with some quick debugging you can figure out that no contour was found in your transformation function - you have the block :

```
if approx_contour is not None and len(approx_contour)==4:
    approx_contour=np.float32(approx_contour)
    dst=four_point_transform(threshold,approx_contour)
```

Just add:

```
else:
    print("no contour found")
```

to see for yourself.

The problem is with your Canny filter. With `apertureSize = 7` your first image works but not the second one, with `apertureSize = 3` your second image work but not the first one.

So both of your image work, but not with the same parameters. If processing time is not an issue for your task, you could iterate several values of the parameters, or else steer away from the Canny method. On both your images the paper is a lot brighter than the background so a convexHull on the threshold image would work.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you please tell me that how can i remove shearness from image . I am trying many codes but not working , if you can tell me other than this approach it will be appreciateable. I just have to remove shearness from it.

Answer (score 1):

Since your initial image is in color, another approach is to use the H place to detect the 'white color' of the paper. I have made some adjustments in the code and it now works for both your images.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import imutils

def order_points(pts):
    """ Return sorted list of corners, from top-left then clockwise """
    pts = np.reshape(pts, (6,2))
    rect = np.zeros((4, 2), dtype = "float32")
    s = pts.sum(axis = 1)
    rect[0] = pts[np.argmin(s)]
    rect[2] = pts[np.argmax(s)]
    diff = np.diff(pts, axis = 1)
    rect[1] = pts[np.argmin(diff)]
    rect[3] = pts[np.argmax(diff)]
    return rect

def four_point_transform(image, pts):
    (tl, tr, br, bl) = rect
    widthA = np.sqrt(((br[0] - bl[0]) ** 2) + ((br[1] - bl[1]) ** 2))
    widthB = np.sqrt(((tr[0] - tl[0]) ** 2) + ((tr[1] - tl[1]) ** 2))
    maxWidth = max(int(widthA), int(widthB))
    heightA = np.sqrt(((tr[0] - br[0]) ** 2) + ((tr[1] - br[1]) ** 2))
    heightB = np.sqrt(((tl[0] - bl[0]) ** 2) + ((tl[1] - bl[1]) ** 2))
    maxHeight = max(int(heightA), int(heightB))
    dst = np.array([
        [0, 0],
        [maxWidth - 1, 0],
        [maxWidth - 1, maxHeight - 1],
        [0, maxHeight - 1]], dtype = "float32")
    M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(rect, dst)
    warped = cv2.warpPerspective(image, M, (maxWidth, maxHeight))
    return warped

image1 = cv2.imread('im1.jpg')
mask = np.zeros(image1.shape, np.uint8)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image1,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Hue thresholding for the white paper
HSV = cv2.cvtColor(image1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
lo_H = 100
hi_H = 200
thresh = cv2.inRange(HSV, (lo_H, 0, 0), (hi_H, 255, 255))

# Find the contour of the paper sheet - use convexhull
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnt = sorted(contours, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)
hull = []
for i in range(len(cnt)):
    hull.append(cv2.convexHull(cnt[i], False))

cv2.drawContours(mask, hull, 0, (255, 255, 255), thickness=cv2.FILLED)

mask = cv2.cvtColor(mask,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.bitwise_and(gray, gray, mask=mask)

# Corner detection - keep 6 best corners 
corners = cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack(mask, 6, 0.01, 50)
corners = np.int0(corners)

# Order the corners and keep 4
rect = order_points(corners)
wrap = four_point_transform(gray, rect)


# Display results
cv2.drawContours(image1, hull, 0, (0,255,125), 3)
cv2.imshow("image", image1)
#cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
#cv2.imshow("mask", mask)
cv2.imshow("gray", gray)
cv2.imshow("wrap", wrap)
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: It is not working for every images . I have tried some more images and it is not properly displaying the output . I have edited my question and added some more images for testing your code . You may run it ..